# Dialogflow CX edition: how to review conversations

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I need to know how to review actual conversations an the intent that were matched for each conversational turn.
I can't find the way to accomplish the conversation/intent review on **Dialogflow CX** edition. (it was pretty simple on ES edition).
I need to access his feature (if it is implemented on CX) because sometimes my agent triggers a wrong intent trying to respond to user input.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Claudia

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday, Dialogflow Support team informed me that at the moment, there is no available feature in Dialogflow CX that is similar to the History or Training features in Dialogflow ES.
Let's hope this feature to be available soon!!!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Dialogflow CX doesn't have that feature. But it's possible if you are choosing any 3rd party tools.

Kommunicate is a tool that supports Dialogflow CX & ES integrations.
It will show the bot intents and their corresponding messages along with categories - Intent, Fallback, Handoff, Smalltalk, and the triggered sentences

This would help to analyze the bot's performance and improve by adding the unanswered/wrong phrases to the bot.

Please refer to the [doc](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/analytics#bot-messages) for more details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DialogFlow CX now has a *Conversation history* tab under its *Manage* tab.

[image]